# ESLint throws an "is missing in props validation" error when use destructuring in function parameter

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm trying to describe table columns and use function parameter destructuring in column "render" function:

```
const columns = [
{
        field: 'description',
        // The parameter is row data object
        render: ({ id, description }) => (
            <Tooltip title={ id }>
                <div>
                    { description }
                </div>
            </Tooltip>
        )
    }
]
```

And I got a "react/prop-types" error

> '"id" is missing in prop validation

Same with "description". So I had to use:

```
render: (task) => (
        <Tooltip title={ task.id }>
            <div>
                { task.description }
            </div>
        </Tooltip>
    )
```

I wonder, maybe it's still possible to use parameter destructuring?

Workaround:

```
"react": "^16.7.0",
"eslint": "^5.3.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
"eslint-plugin-react-app": "^4.0.1"
```

**EDIT**:

I desided just to add eslint-disable-next-line for such code fragments

Comment: I think you're meant to create the components separately, so `const DescriptionTooltip = ({ id, ...}) => blah;` and then `DescriptionTooltip.proptypes = whatever`. Then in your columns thing just do `... render: DescriptionTooltip ...`

Comment: @david yeah, I've thought about it, but I don't really want to create a separate component because it won't be re-usable. But I'll keep your suggestion in mind, thanks!

Comment: You can just create it in the same file. Things don't have to be reusable to be split out and described on their own separately from where they are used.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about destructuring, it's just because eslint interprets `columns.render` as a component and asks that you document its props.

You can still define `columns.render.propTypes` to satisfy eslint.

```
    const columns = [
        {
            field: 'description',
            // The parameter is row data object
            render: ({ id, description }) => (
                <Tooltip title={ id }>
                    <div>
                        { description }
                    </div>
                </Tooltip>
            )
        }
    ];
    columns.render.propTypes = {
        id: PropTypes.string,
        description: PropTypes.string,
    };
```

Comment: That sounds logical, but I still get this error even when columns.render.propTypes are described =(